# What are the best ways to deal with these PDFSharp table limitations?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using PDFSharp to export a table to PDF (using the regular MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table object).  It works great except I ran into a few issues:

1. if the content of a single cell in the table is longer than the height of the page it seems like the content just gets cut off.  A table itself can span multiple pages but a row seems like it can only be 1 page high and It seems like it doesn't extend onto the next page.

Is there any workaround to this or is this just a bug in the library?

2. Also for tables that span multiple pages, is there a way to have the header row on the table show up at the top of every page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re first question:
It's documented that MigraDoc does not break table rows over multiple pages. It's not a bug, it's a limitation. So it's up to you to design the tables that this does not cause problems.
IIRC there is a hack published on the PDFsharp forum that increases the page height to work around this problem. If you only need PDFfiles, this could be a workaround.

Edit: Didn't find the link when I made the post, but found it today when I tried again: Here's the workaround:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=4311#p4311
I didn't try it myself.

Re second question:
Rows marked as header rows will be repeated on every new page. Just set the HeadingFormat property of those rows to true.

Comment: thanks for the response . . I couldn't find the published "hack".  I only need PDF.  Can you include a link in your response and i will accept the answer

Comment: Added the link to my answer - tonight I had more luck searching for the right post ...